# <input (selectItem)="selectedItem($event)"> not working in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an input element, when I type a character it will give some suggestion and I can select it, I want to access the item that I selected, for this I defined a method "selectedItem($event)"

```
<input type="text" (selectItem)="selecteditem($event)">
```

and my method is :

```
selectedItem (items: any) { 
    console.log('selected item is ' + items)
}
```

on my console I am getting:

```
selected item is [object Object]
```

It should show selected item but it is showing array of object.

If i try to `print items[0]` I will get `undefined` on console.

What is the problem with this ?

Comment: you are passing event, how you will get items. that console is event Object

Comment: change your code like this selectedItem($event.value)

Comment: after changing it is showing ,"selected item is undefined" on console,
but when i hover on the items(in debugging mode it will show item)

Comment: in debugging mode item showing what kind of data ?

Comment: Can you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: yesterday, in debugging mode  it was showing the item(string) that i select from the suggestion dropdown list, but today it is showing undefined.

Answer (score 1):

What does 'selectItem' represent ? Because its obviously not a native input element listener, and a custom directive. This is something you need to provide more context around next time.

I am assuming `items` represents an object, and your console.log is adding a string to an object will cast the object to a string (Try `"" + {}`) in your console.

To solve this problem you want to pass the `items` as a second parameter to console.log so your object is not casted to a string. You can do so like this

`console.log('selected item is ', items)`

```js
obj = {name: 'realappie'}

console.log("name is" + obj);

console.log("name is", obj);
```

Comment: console.log('selected item is ', items)

this one also showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

Output items data is an object. We should convert it to a string, then it will work:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(items))`